# Split a string, remember the positions of splitting

Tags: php

Assume I have the following string:

```
I have | been very busy lately and need to go | to bed early
```

By splitting on "|", you get:

```
$arr = array(
  [0] => I have
  [1] => been very busy lately and need to go
  [2] => to bed early
)
```

The first split is after 2 words, and the second split 8 words after that. The positions after how many words to split will be stored: array(2, 8, 3). Then, the string is imploded to be passed on to a custom string tagger:

```
tag_string('I have been very busy lately and need to go to bed early');
```

I don't know what the output of tag_string will be exactly, except that the total words will remain the same. Examples of output would be:

```
I have-nn been-vb very-vb busy lately and-rr need to-r go to bed early-p
I-ee have been-vb very busy-df lately-nn and need-f to go to bed-uu early-yy
```

This will lengthen the string by an unknown number of characters. I have no control over tag_string. What I know is (1) the number of words will be the same as before and (2) the array was split after 2, and thereafter after 8 words, respectively. I now need a solution explode the tagged string into the same array as before:

```
$string = "I have-nn been-vb very-vb busy lately and-rr need to-r go to bed early-p"
function split_string_again() {
  // split after 2nd, and thereafter after 8th word
}
```

With output:

```
$arr = array(
  [0] => I have-nn
  [1] => been-vb very-vb busy lately and-rr need to-r go
  [2] => to bed early-p
)
```

So to be clear (I wasn't before): I cannot split by remembering the strpos, because strpos before and after the string went through the tagger, aren't the same. I need to count the number of words. I hope I have made myself more clear :)

Comment: You could explode it and then `strlen` each part of the array

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing what you are attempting to do, if it is anything more advanced you might be interested in the [Rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) -- though implementing it in PHP could be "slow".

Comment: @evolve I think I explained it better now - see the edit of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, although I think the [rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) still applies it might be a little overkill since word placement won't change. Here is my solution:

```
$str = "I have | been very busy lately and need to go | to bed early";

function get_breaks($str)
{
    $breaks = array();
    $arr = explode("|", $str);

    foreach($arr as $val)
    {
        $breaks[] = str_word_count($val);
    }

    return $breaks;
}

$breaks = get_breaks($str);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($breaks, 1) . "</pre>";

$str = str_replace("|", "", $str);

function rebreak($str, $breaks)
{
    $return = array();
    $old_break = 0;

    $arr = str_word_count($str, 1);

    foreach($breaks as $break)
    {
        $return[] = implode(" ", array_slice($arr, $old_break, $break));

        $old_break += $break;
    }

    return $return;
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r(rebreak($str, $breaks), 1) . "</pre>";

echo "<pre>" . print_r(rebreak("I have-nn been-vb very-vb busy lately and-rr need to-r go to bed early-p", $breaks), 1) . "</pre>";
```

Let me know if you have any questions, but it is pretty self explanatory.  There are definitely ways to improve this as well.

Comment: Thanks! Your help is appreciated. There was a small oversight, that was easy enough to fix:  $old_break = $break; had to be  $old_break+= $break; I looked at the rope data structure, but it indeed seems overkill since there is only this specific operation that I need to be done.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't want to count the number of words, you would want to count the string length ([`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen)). If it is the same string without the pipes, then you want to split it with [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) after a certain amount.

```
$strCounts = array();

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $strCounts[] = strlen($item);
}

// Later on.
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($strCounts as $count) {
     $arr[] = substr($string, $i, $count);
     $i += $count; // increment the start position by the length
}
```

I have not tested this, simply a "theory" and probably has some kinks to work out. There may be a better way to go about it, I just don't know it.

Comment: +1 for `strlen` vs word count. I think the question appears more complicated than the actual solution merits.

Comment: strlen isn't a solution (but it looked like it because I was unclear in my question). Please see the edited OP.

Comment: If I have some time later I will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understood what you actually wanted to achieve. But here are a couple of things that might help you:

[str_word_count()](http://php.net/str_word_count) counts the number of words in a string. `preg_match_all('/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\x{2019}]*/u', $string, $foo);` does pretty much the same, but on UTF-8 strings.

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) finds the first occurrence of a string within another. You could easily find the positions of all | with this:

```
$pos = -1;
$positions = array();
while (($pos = strpos($string, '|', $pos + 1)) !== false) {
  $positions[] = $pos;
}
```

I'm still not sure I understood why you can't just use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) for this, though.

```
<?php
$string = 'I have | been very busy lately and need to go | to bed early';
$parts = explode('|', $string);
$words = array();
foreach ($parts as $s) {
  $words[] = str_word_count($s);
}
```

Comment: strpos is not useful here (although it looked like it since I wasn't clear in my question). Please see the updated OP and tell me what you think.